# Jquery validate plugin disabled attribute bug

Tags: jquery-validate

I have a set of html input:checkbox items. One of these items has *disabled* attribute.
Expected behavior is that jquery validation plugin will ignore *input* with *disabled* attribute, but will process validation on other elements which are not disabled.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="1" minlength="1" required="required" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="2" minlength="1" required="required" />
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="3" minlength="1" required="required" />
```

I've created a live example to demonstrate the behavior. http://jsfiddle.net/cVMBA/24/

The expected behavior is that at least one checkbox is selected in this case. If not, then the error should appear.
Although as I can see  the behavior is really strange. If you look in console you can see that at first *errorPlacement* function is fired and afterward *unhighlight* function fires. So the problem here is that error is not shown.

When you remove attribute *disabled="disabled"* the plugin will work as expected.
Any ideas, or maybe a hack to override this behavior?

Comment: It's working perfect for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/4fShN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is working fine regarding the `disabled="disabled"` attribute as demonstrated here:  http://jsfiddle.net/4fShN/

Regarding your code:

```
$('#test_validate').validate({
    ignore : [],
    unhighlight : function(element, errorClass, validClass){
         $('#test_validate').removeClass('error-highlighted');
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {           
        $('#test_validate').addClass('error-highlighted').find('.error-div').text('Select radio button');
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('form ok');
    }
});
```

You are missing the `highlight` callback function, which is the complement to the `unhighlight` callback.  You should note that `errorPlacement` only fires when *initially* placing the error `label` element.  If you want toggling along with the error, then that's what `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions are supposed to be used for.

Also, your code is applying the class to `$('#test_validate')`, which contains the `id` of your `<form>` element.  Typically, you apply & remove the class from the `<input>` element with the error by using the included `element` parameter.

```
    highlight : function(element, errorClass, validClass){
        $(element).addClass('error-highlighted');
    },
    unhighlight : function(element, errorClass, validClass){
        $(element).removeClass('error-highlighted');
    },
```

To make things even simpler, the above code can be removed by simply defining your `validClass` and `errorClass` options.  Why can they be removed?  Because the two functions above are basically the same as the default plugin behavior.

```
errorClass: "error-highlighted",
validClass: "valid"
```

**See documentation**:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and great answer! This makes perfect sense!